# Alignment of Figure tile within enumerate function in Latex

Tags: latex, alignment, enumeration

I have a latex document in which I have included two images side by side within an enumerate function. The caption for those individual figures is aligned to the figure itself, but the overall Figure title is not aligned with the enumerate function instead it is aligned with the rest of the document. It could probably be a quick fix, but I am unable to find it. Can anybody help, please?

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Consider the two figures given below,
\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
            \centering
            \subfloat[\centering Figure 1 title.]
            {
                {
                    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Figures/Figure_1.png}
                }
                \label{Figure_1}
            }
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
            \centering
            \subfloat[\centering Figure 2 title.]
            {
                {
                    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Figures/Figure_.png}
                }
                \label{fig:Figure_2}
            }
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{Common title for figure 1 and figure.}%
        \label{fig:fig:power_response}
    \end{figure}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: If you need figures at a particular position and don't want them to float, don't use a floating environment like `figure`.  You can use the caption package to add a caption without a float